# Windows Phone 8 App Development using Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I want to develop windows phone 8 app using Phonegap. I have used phonegap for Android and iOS and it works fine. As per my research, I have found some prerequisites to develop WP8 apps using phonegap are:

1. Node.js
2. Windows phone SDK
3. IE10
4. A 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro
5. Windows Phone SDK
6. Visual Studio 2012 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate

I have windows 7 installed on my system. My question is: Can I develop WP8 apps using phonegap in Windows 7. I have not found any material regarding this.
Thanks.

Comment: "You need x64bit Win8 pro to develop a phonegap app." "Yeah, but can I do it in windows 7?" "ಠ_ಠ"

Comment: @Will Thanks for the answer. I just wanted to know if it is possible with Windows 7. I have upgraded my system to windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

When developing locally (ex: using Visual Studio, the Cordova CLI, Ionic CLI, or PhoneGap CLI local builds), these are the requirements [per MSDN re: Windows Phone 8.0 SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402529(v=vs.105).aspx):

> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 requires 64-bit Windows 8 Pro or higher. You
>   can't develop Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows 7, on Windows Server
>   2008, or on Windows Server 2012. The Windows Phone 8 Emulator has
>   special hardware, software, and configuration requirements. For more
>   info, see System requirements for the emulator for Windows Phone 8.